# Error in SCUP Catalog Import

Tags: wsus, sccm

Trying to get SCUP running on a system but having some difficulties.  SCUP installed fine, and I have configured group policy and a CA published certificate as expected.  However, when I try to import any catalog, it errors out as follows:

```
Launching expand.exe  with arguments: -R "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\2\\fdushzom.4gk\AdobeFlashPlayerCatalog_SCUP.cab" -F:* "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\2\\iegdaw4t.ar4"
    Microsoft (R) File Expansion Utility  Version 6.3.9600.17415

    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Adding C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\2\\iegdaw4t.ar4\AdobeFlashPlayerCatalog_SCUP.xml to Extraction Queue

    Expanding Files ....

    Expanding Files Complete ...

Extraction completed with exit code 0
Import: Importing updates from C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\2\\iegdaw4t.ar4\AdobeFlashPlayerCatalog_SCUP.xml
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Import: XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
1 results from import added to wizard.
ImportProgress: Background processing completed.
```

SCUP is installed on the same machine as WSUS (Server 2012 R2) and is a SUP for SCCM.  WSUS is using SQL Server 2014 cluster for SUSDB.  If any more environment info is required, please let me know.

Comment: These information is not indicating problem with SCUP, instead something with catalog. Available catalogs are here https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/sccm.html and follow this guide to import some of catalog for testing purpose.

Comment: I've been through that site, even manually downloaded the cabs and tried, even a couple different versions of the cabs, since they updated while I've been testing and it's always the same error.  I don't think that the issue is with the files themselves, otherwise lots of other people would be complaining about broken Adobe updates.  Thank you for your response, though.  I appreciate you taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. What's the version of your SCUP and WSUS? Was there any information in system event viewer? Check your temp folder to see if any strange things there. Any antivirus programs running there? I'm asking because these factors may lead to unexpected issues.

Comment: SCUP: 5.00.1727.0000
WSUS: 6.3.9600.18228
Nothing in event logs.  No access issues to temp folder. No blocks from AV

Comment: Have you tried to install SCUP on another server? It's possible that it's with the OS.

Comment: I haven't, no.  But it needs to be this server anyway, so need to fix it for this machine.

Comment: Remove all Adobe catalogs from SCUP Catalog workspace, try to add another Partner Catalog like HP. Then check if you can import updates from HP catalog. Any chance that you run SFC /SCANNOW to check if any system file error;

Comment: All catalogs attempted have the same error.  Running sfc scan.

Comment: Please Remove all vendor's folder from Updates - All Software Updates and then try to import. If this is not helpful, Could you try again following guide http://gerryhampsoncm.blogspot.sg/2013/04/sccm-2012-sp1-step-by-step-guide-part_27.html.  This guide works in my lab.

Comment: Ok, so SFC /SCANNOW didn't help, but running DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following fixed the issue:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```